# Contador de notificações apresentando total inconsistente?

Tags: suporte, notificações

Após alcançar a reputação de 10mil, foram me apresentadas novas ferramentas de moderação, e agora a notificação parece contabilizar mais coisas, além de simplesmente edições sugeridas. Já li aqui no meta que esta marca de rep faz com que as notificações exibam o total de tudo que está na fila pendente de analise, mas o contador está conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, nas filas de analise, o total é bem inferior:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria isso um bug?

Answer (score 3):

O que mostra na barra é o total de análises pendentes. O que mostra na página separado por tipo é o que você pode analisar. Em geral não pode analisar o que já analisou e não foi resolvido por alguma razão. Ou precisa de outras pessoas analisarem ou você pulou, ou talvez tenha algum outro motivo que eu não sei ou não lembro.

Comment: Então aquele total lá é de pendencias das filas, incluindo o que eu já vi e votei?

Comment: isso...........