# O que é esta sinalização?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise, interface-usuário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que quer dizer esta sinalização, não deveria aparecer apenas a utilizadores com mais de `3.000` de reputação?

Comment: Acho que a bolinha vermelha se refere aos "Votos para fechar" só que você ainda não reputação para acessá-la dai ela não aparece na lista para você

Comment: @Math então não deveria aparecer, se não tenho reputação suficiente.

Comment: @Articuno penso serem questões diferentes..

Comment: Sempre foi assim, a antiga notificação sempre mostrava coisas pendentes, mas quem tem menos de 10.000 não conseguia ver do que se tratava, apenas que havia pendencias.

Comment: @Tmc sim, to procurando uma pergunta aqui no meta que tratava disso na interface antiga, mas não lembro bem como a pergunta foi perguntada para encontra-la

Comment: Relacionado: [Contador de sugestões de edição está incoerente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1282/3117)

Comment: Relacionado: [Contador de notificações apresentando total inconsistente?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5607/contador-de-notificações-apresentando-total-inconsistente)

Comment: @Math existe algum bug no aparecimento disso para utilizadores com menos de 10.000 ou consideram como um acontecimento normal?

Comment: @Tmc sobre as bolinhas não achei nada no metão, mas acho que é tratado como [feature](https://geekwhisperin.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/bug-vs-feature.jpg) assim como era na interface anterior

Comment: @Math ok explicado :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O mais provável é que a bolinha vermelha que você está vendo no momento se refira à fila de votos para fechar, que só aparece para usuários com 3k+ de reputação:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não achei nada oficial no Metão sobre a nova interface, mas assim como haviam [incoerências](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282/contador-de-sugest%C3%B5es-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-incoerente) na interface anterior é possível que tenham mantido o comportamento para a nova.

Comment: E também devido a um cache (back-end), pois muita coisa não é em "tempo real", acredito eu :)

Comment: É estranho olhar a _screenshot_ da pergunta linkada e ver a fila de fechamento com menos de 100 itens :p